# Dynamic modal: hiding / unhiding modal form elements in Kendo UI

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

Within a modal, there is a dropdown. It lists, among other things, "Users" and "Products", and "Pets". If "Users" is selected, I need to populate yet another dropdown directly below it with Users.all or Products.all - If "Pets" is selected, no additional form element is needed. I have been able to wrap the secondary dropdown in a div called "secondary" and hide it via CSS, but I am having issues accessing it in the console. It seems that, since this is in a modal, it is not accessable via the DOM. Is this true? Can someone please recommend a Kendo technique to make this dynamic form? Thank you.

DOUMENTATION: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler#methods-addEvent

Code gist: https://gist.github.com/piratebroadcast/c95da64f56cc3cf40bc126d3ba936a3f

Comment: Could you please paste your code so that we can have a better starting point.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/piratebroadcast/c95da64f56cc3cf40bc126d3ba936a3f